# java.sql.SQLException: near “.”: syntax error

Tags: java, sqlite, mysql-error-1064, sqliteopenhelper

I wrote a program that populates a database with a list of words. Problem is, it throws up the "Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: near ".": syntax error" every time I try to run the code.
This I turn to you for help.

This is the code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
```

And here is the source:

```
public Account() {
            super("Create Account");
            initComponents();
            conn=javaconnect.ConnecrDb();
            RandomAcc();
            RandomMICR();
            RandomPIN();
        }

    public void RandomAcc(){
        Random ra=new Random();
        jTextField1.setText(""+ra.nextInt(10000+1));
    }
    public void RandomMICR(){
        Random ra=new Random();
        jTextField2.setText(""+ra.nextInt(1000+1));
    }
    public void RandomPIN(){
        Random ra=new Random();
        jTextField3.setText(""+ra.nextInt(1000+1));
    }
    public void Bal(){
        String sql="insert into Balances(Name,Acc,MICR_No,Balance) values(?,?,?,?)";
        try{
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, jTextField5.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jTextField2.getText());
        pst.setString(4, jTextField10.getText());
        pst.execute();   
    }catch(Exception e){`enter code here`
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
 }

String sql="insert into Account(Acc,Name,DOB,Pin,Acc_Type,Nationality,Caste,MICR_No,Gender,Mob,Address,Sec.Q,Sec.A,Balance) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try{
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jTextField5.getText());
        pst.setString(3,((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
        pst.setString(4, jTextField3.getText());
        pst.setString(5, (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
        pst.setString(6, (String) jComboBox2.getSelectedItem());
        pst.setString(7, jTextField6.getText());
        pst.setString(8, jTextField2.getText());

        jRadioButton1.setActionCommand("Male");
        jRadioButton2.setActionCommand("Female");
        pst.setString(9, buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand()); 

        pst.setString(10, jTextField7.getText());
        pst.setString(11, jTextField4.getText());
        pst.setString(12, (String) jComboBox3.getSelectedItem());
        pst.setString(13, jTextField9.getText());
        pst.setString(14, jTextField10.getText());
        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congrtz\n Account has been Created");
        Bal();
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: please paste full error stack. and what is "Sec.Q,Sec.A" in your insert statement?

Comment: Sec.Q,Sec.A it's mean Security Question and Security Answer

Comment: I'm sure your database doesn't have column names with dots in them.  Check your table definition, to see what the column names really are, and fix them in the insert statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String sql="insert into Account(Acc,Name,DOB,Pin,Acc_Type,Nationality,Caste,MICR_No,Gender,Mob,Address,Sec.Q,Sec.A,Balance) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Are `Sec.Q,Sec.A`  column names? It is not allowed.

[Database name restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506161/database-name-restrictions)